# Printing contents of a doubly linked circular list in c prints out only first node

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I'm trying to print out the values of a doubly linked circular list, but my printAll function only prints out the contents of the first node for some reason.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct clientsOn
{
    int id;
    char filename[20];
    struct clientsOn* next;
    struct clientsOn* prev;
};

struct clientsList
{
    int count;
    struct clientsOn* head;
};

void printAll(struct clientsList* list);
void add(struct clientsList *list,struct clientsOn *newC);
struct clientsList* createList();
struct clientsOn* createNode(char* profile);

main()
{
struct clientsList* people = malloc(sizeof(struct clientsList));
people = createList();
printf("Number of people currently on: %d\n",people->count);

struct clientsOn* pers1, *pers2, *pers3;

char boy[20],boy2[20],boy3[20];
printf("String: \n");
scanf("%s",boy);
printf("String: \n");
scanf("%s",boy2);
printf("String: \n");
scanf("%s",boy3);

pers1 = createNode(boy);
pers2 = createNode(boy2);
pers3 = createNode(boy3);

add(people,pers1);
add(people,pers2);
add(people,pers3);
printf("people count: %d", people->count);

printAll(people);
}

struct clientsList* createList()
{
    struct clientsList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct clientsList));
    if(list){
        list->head = NULL;
        list->count = 0;
    }
    return list;
}

struct clientsOn* createNode(char* profile)
{
    struct clientsOn* clients = malloc(sizeof(struct clientsOn));

    if(clients){
        clients->next = clients;
        clients->prev = clients;
        strcpy(clients->filename,profile);
    }
    return clients;
}

void add(struct clientsList *list,struct clientsOn *newC)
{

    if(newC){
    if(list->head == NULL){
        list->head = newC;
    }else{
        list->head->prev = newC;
        newC->prev = list->head->prev;
        newC->prev->next = newC;
        newC->next = list->head;
    }
    list->count++;
    }
}

void printAll(struct clientsList* list)
{
    struct clientsOn* node = list->head;

    if(node != NULL){
        do{
            printf("list content is: %s",node->filename);
            node = node->next;
        }while(node!=list->head);
    }
}
```

My add function adds nodes to the very end of the list and when I output the list count

```
printf("people count: %d", people->count);
```

it shows the number of items added to the list, however when I try to print out the individual items,

```
printAll(people);
```

it doesn't go beyond the first node. Anyone ever experience anything similar?

Comment: "*it doesn't go beyond ... ever experience anything similar*" Yeah, kinda, while playin' with young horses ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your `add()` function, there is an issue which does not create the list appropriately.

```
list->head->prev = newC;  //sets head->prev to newC
newC->prev = list->head->prev; //here setting newC->prev to head->prev which is NewC
newC->prev->next = newC; //here newC->prev->next is actually newC->next is set to newC
```

Try to use gdb or some other debugger to verify your logic.

Comment: 1+ not at least for for proposing to use a debugger!

Comment: Thanks for the tip it works with your changes, guess I had my logic all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

In **add** function try to use this logic. I think is it should work.

```
if(newC){
    if(list->head == NULL){
        list->head = newC;
    }else{
        newC->next = list->head;
        newC->prev = list->head->prev;
        list->head->prev->next = newC;
        list->head->prev = newC;
    }
    list->count++;
    }
```

better try with `GDB` or if you want to understand the logic you may use diagrams first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll try using GDB to understand better from now on